# CICD using jenkins which is installed in other machine

Tags: jenkins, cicd

Suppose I have two machine ( A & B ) and i have jenkins installed in machine A , can I deploy in machine B using Jenkins installed in machine A? I am using Jenkins Multibranch pipeline

Answer (score 2):

If your question is can Jenkins deploy to machine B then the answer is absolutely!  Jenkins provides documentation on deployments [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/deployment/), and has an example of a multibranch pipeline deployment [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/#add-deliver-and-deploy-stages-to-your-pipeline).

If you want machine B to deploy to a different computer (e.g. machine C) then you can do this by configuring machine B to be an "agent", and following the deployment guides linked to above.